# How do I create a Scratch Org with Digital Engagement enabled?

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, digital-engagement

I need a `Scratch Org` with `Digital Engagement` enabled.

- [Digital Engagement](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/service-cloud/digital-engagement/)
- [Digital Engagement for Sales Cloud](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sales_core_digital_engagment.htm&type=5)

Which [Scratch Org Feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) do I need to use to achieve this?

I cannot see any mention of `Digital Engagement` in the Scratch Org Features documentation.

Comment: I am getting this error also when adding "DigitalEngagement"
When I add "LiveMessage", this works and I can see Messaging in setup. How ever I do not have the permissions to create a new channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, this feature existed in the past but the Digital Engagement feature for scratch orgs appears to be removed as of now. I recommend [creating a support case](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&language=en_us) for confirmation

I think you can no longer add the "DigitalEngagement" feature to the scratch org definition file. When we look at the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_scratch_org_features.htm?edition=&impact=) now, this is not included

The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sales_core_digital_engagment.htm&type=5) states this is available for an extra cost in: Enterprise and Unlimited Editions as per this so if you have this license or this feature enabled (AFAIK this requires Chat ser License, Messaging user permission set license. I recommend reaching out to your Account Executive

I can confirm that the name of the feature in the past was definitely DigitalEngagement

I believe using this file gives an error at this time. However, you can give a try

```
Org JSON def (project-scratch-def.json)

{

"orgName":"hello9ajcm",

"edition":"Developer",

"features":["DigitalEngagement"]

}
```

> ERROR running force:org:create: DigitalEngagement is not a valid Features value.

Comment: Thanks, Anudeep. I have raised a case.